# RegEx is allowing white spaces

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I need to validate phone number. The below satisfies my requirement except that it allows whitespaces in between. Meaning, if I give 12 123 it is allowing white spaces. How can I correct it?

```
regEx = "[-+()0-9]{1,20}"
```

Comment: Missing anchors `^` and `$`. `"^[-+()0-9]{1,20}$"`

Comment: [tag:javascript] or [tag:java]. Both are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is matching only the first digit and ignoring the rest because what it found satisfied the expression.

try this: `"^[-+()0-9]{1,20}$"`

Answer (score 0):

Anchor was missing in your pattern.

```
var ptn = "1212121";
var regEx = "^[-+()0-9]{1,20}$";
var reg = new RegExp(regEx,"g");
var match_ = ptn.match(reg);
console.log(match_);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java I would go for:

```
"^(\\(?\\+?[0-9]{1,3}\\)?)?\\s+[\\s-+()0-9]{1,20}$"
```

Maximum phone number length is 15 digits I think.

Comment: thank you for your answer.But my requirement allows 20 digits :)